# ArcGIS sync replica not working with REST API

Tags: arcgis-10.5

I have created a replica using CreateReplica REST API for offline use. Data format is SQLite. Now I am trying to sync replica. 
Steps I have followed for sync:
 1. Uploaded my geodatabase file.
 2. Used upload id item in SyncReplica REST API.

```
Error:
Sync replica gives error as - can not import data.
```

I am not getting what is exact issue. How can I figure out the issue?